# Converting c# to vb.net base class overrided function with different parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, overriding

I need your help to convert an overrided function from c# to vb.net.  Here's the story:

The c# code has a base class called TreeViewerDataProviderBase with a function stubbed like so:

```
Protected Overridable Function CreateTreeNode(parentNode As TreeNodePath, text As String, path As String, isFile As Boolean, addDummyNode As Boolean, isSpecialFolder As Boolean) As TreeNodePath
```

Another class subclasses TreeViewerDataProviderBase, and overrides the base function with this stub:

```
    protected virtual TreeNodePath CreateTreeNode(System.Windows.Forms.TreeNodeCollection parentCollection, TreeNodePath parentNode, Datomp.Win32.ShellItem shellItem)
```

As you can see, the base function and the overrided function has the same first 2 params, but the rest are different.

When I attempt to convert this to vb.net, I get:

```
        Protected Overridable Function CreateTreeNode(parentCollection As System.Windows.Forms.TreeNodeCollection, parentNode As TreeNodePath, shellItem As DotNetParts.Win32.ShellItem) As TreeNodePath
```

Which gives me an error that CreateTreeNode overrides a method in the base class and must be declared 'overrides'.

However, when I change it from Overridable to Overrides, I get ANOTHER error, that it does not override a method in the base class!  It's a chicken and egg problem.

I'm a c# guy, so I don't understand why this is not ok.  If I try to remove the Overrides, I get yet ANOTHER ERROR, that it overrides a base class function!  Ack.

Could some VB.NET/C# genius help me to convert this?

Comment: Can you display your actual base class from C#?

Comment: shellitem is not of the same type. If they are different types you need to overload the method, not override it.

Comment: C#: `Datomp.Win32.ShellItem shellItem`, VB: `shellItem As DotNetParts.Win32.ShellItem`. The types differ. A function can only override its base function if the types match completely.

Comment: That's the answer Sam Axe!  Thanks so much for your answer, and thanks everyone for responding so quickly.  I have to say, as a programmer of over 30 years, but a newbie to stackoverflow (where have I BEEN, I know!), this site is incredible!  Can someone tell me how to credit Sam with the answer?  I don't see any way of doing that...

Comment: @AndrewH your options are the keywords `overloads` or `shadows`. Read [shadows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/1h3wytf6.aspx) and [overloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybxdk47f.aspx) for more info. Credit: Sam needs to create a answer out of his comment. You can then accept his answer.

Comment: Hey Sam.  Can you create an answer out of your comment?  I want to credit you with the answer...

Comment: @AndrewH glad to have helped. The answer is unlikely to be useful to a larger audience so I'll leave the credit to your answer below. In the future if you want someone to be notified that you are talking to them you'll need to place an @ in front of their name. The stackoverflow faq is a good place to learn about things like that. Enjoy Vb!

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem doing as Sam Axe stated above and replaced the `Overridable` with `Overloads`

So this:

```
Protected Overridable Function CreateTreeNode(parentCollection As System.Windows.Forms.TreeNodeCollection, parentNode As TreeNodePath, shellItem As DotNetParts.Win32.ShellItem) As TreeNodePath
```

Became this:

```
Protected Overloads Function CreateTreeNode(parentCollection As System.Windows.Forms.TreeNodeCollection, parentNode As TreeNodePath, shellItem As DotNetParts.Win32.ShellItem) As TreeNodePath
```